# vue - Bootstrap-vue: Select row (primary-key) based on an object with the same key values

Tags: bootstrap-vue

how can I select each rows with the same values from a separate object?

```
<b-table
:items="CurrentObject"
:select-mode="selectMode"
ref="selectableTable"
selectable
@row-selected="onRowSelected"
primary-key="uniqueID"
>
```

CurrentObject:

```
[
{name: 'A', uniqueID: 123, text: 'lorem ipsum'},
{name: 'B', uniqueID: 456, text: 'lorem ipsum'},
{name: 'C', uniqueID: 789, text: 'lorem ipsum'},
]
```

Separate Object:

```
[
{uniqueID: 123},
{uniqueID: 456},
{uniqueID: 789},
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JavaScript's [`array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and VueBootstrap's [`selectRow()`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#row-select-support) seem to do it.

**Template:**

```
<template> 
  <b-container>
    <div>
      <h1>Current Object</h1>
      <b-table
      :items="currentObject"
      :select-mode="selectMode"
      ref="selectableTable"
      selectable
      @row-selected="onRowSelected"
      primary-key="uniqueID"
      >
      </b-table>
      <h2>Separate Object</h2>
      <div v-for='object in separateObject' @click='selectMyRow(object.uniqueID);'>{{ object.uniqueID }}</div>
    </div>
  </b-container>
</template>
```

**Script:**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {

  selectMode = 'single';

  currentObject = [
    {name: 'A', uniqueID: 123, text: 'lorem ipsum'},
    {name: 'B', uniqueID: 456, text: 'lorem ipsum'},
    {name: 'C', uniqueID: 789, text: 'lorem ipsum'},
  ];

  separateObject = [
    {uniqueID: 123},
    {uniqueID: 456},
    {uniqueID: 789},
  ];

  selectMyRow(uniqueID) {
    const row = this.currentObject.findIndex(x => x.uniqueID === uniqueID);
    this.$refs.selectableTable.selectRow(row);
  }

  onRowSelected() {
    // do something else
  }
}
</script>
```

Working example:
[image]

If instead, you need similar functionality using select-mode `multi`, use the following:

```
selectMode = 'multi';
...

  selectMyRow(uniqueID) {
    const row = this.currentObject.findIndex(x => x.uniqueID === uniqueID);
    const table = this.$refs.selectableTable
    if (table.isRowSelected(row)) {
      table.unselectRow(row);
    } else {
      table.selectRow(row);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Works like a charm.

Realy. Many thanks for your effort.

That helps me a lot.

But I'am stuggle again:
I am currently working on a solution with "selectMode = 'multi';" ...

https://jsfiddle.net/Arkanto/d4a2rmqu/

Comment: I added sample code to handle multi select. Glad it helped.

Comment: if you know how - quite easy ;-)
I learned a lot. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have the first solution for me.

I couldn't update the jsfiddle yet ...

I have 2 watch functions, each with a for loop

the first loop checks whether in separateArray

```
var TableStore = this.TableStore; // -> ARRAY NO OBJECT
for (var i = 0; i < TableStore.length; i++) {
const row = this.CurrentArray.findIndex(x => x.unID === TableStore[i]);
this.$refs.selectableTable.selectRow(row);
}
```

the second checks whether not.
(filter / includes -> CurrentArray - SeparateArray)

Answer (score 0):

The two offered solutions only work if **sorting, filtering or pagination** are not being used.

This is because `items`, in this case `currentObject`, doesn't represent the actual visual items.

To select the correct item when using sorting, filtering or pagination, you have to use:

```
this.$refs.selectableTable.computedItems.findIndex(x => x.uniqueID === uniqueID);
```

I've created a fiddle providing a working adaption of Mike's code when sorting is used:

https://jsfiddle.net/jz59wn18/